# Lumen dot in URL

Tags: laravel, routes, lumen

I am serving a file via Lumen route and URL contains dot and extension file. and when URL contains dot Lumen look for resources not executing routes.

I've tried to run it on production server and it works but on development environment it does not work.

This is my route:

```
$router->get('file/{file}', function (Request $request, $file) {
    echo $file;
});
```

When I try to open this URL route will be run:
`http://localhost:9001/file/photo.jpg`

When I try to open this URL Lumen look for resources:
`http://localhost:9001/file/photojpg`

Comment: How are you serving the lumen app? Using apache or nginx or php -S ?

Comment: @Shuvojit I'm using `php -S` on local which does not work. but it works with Apache on CentOS

Comment: Yep, that's a php webserver's issue, http://localhost:9001/index.php/file/photo.jpg will work, otherwise won't. I don't know a solution that'll make it work in php websever as of now.